# How to sort word frequency in a list (but not all of them printed) in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, counter

I have to count the word frequency in a list using python, but what I want is I want to count the words according to its occurance, but I dont't want to print it all

For the example, i have this list

```
lists = ["me","sleep","love","me","love","love","love","rain","love","me","me","rain","book","book","rain","book","catch","watch"]
```

If I use this:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(lists)
print(counts)
```

it will come result:

```
Counter({'love': 5, 'me': 4, 'rain': 3, 'book': 3, 'sleep': 1, 'catch': 1, 'watch': 1})
```

But my expected result is:

```
Sort by 4 words that have highest occurance
Love : 5
Me : 4
Rain : 3
Book : 3
```

So "sleep","catch" and "watch" will not be included in my result
How do I modify my code so my code will have output like my expected result, I mean sort by XX words that have highest value of occurance.

Thank you very much

Comment: it's not sorting, its filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(lists).most_common(4)
print ("Sort by 4 words that have highest occurance")
print ("\n".join([str(x)+ " : " + str(y) for x,y in counts]))
```

output:

```
Sort by 4 words that have highest occurance
love : 5
me : 4
rain : 3
book : 3
sleep : 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much :D, it solved by sorting problem...... but how can I rewrite the output so it will be exactly same as my expected result? so the result will be better readable :D thanks before

Comment: once you are able to get most common elements, you should be able to do it, so is not code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I modify my code so my code will have output like my expected result

```
from collections import Counter


lists = ["me","sleep","love","me","love","love","love","rain","love",
         "me","me","rain","book","book","rain","book","catch","watch"]

counts = Counter(lists).most_common(4)
print ("Sort by 4 words that have highest occurance")
for word, count in counts:
    print("{} : {}".format(word.title(), count))
```

Output

```
Sort by 4 words that have highest occurance
Love : 5
Me : 4
Book : 3
Rain : 3
```

Note: no rule is specified for ordering entries with duplicate values, e.g. `Book` and `Rain`